# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ACE' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x

Nao sei como resolver estou tentando criar um sistema de acelearacao. arcade e uma api que estou ultilizando e pouca conheecida

```
import arcade
import os

SPRITE_SCALING = 0.5

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
SCREEN_TITLE = "Move Sprite with Keyboard Example"

MOVEMENT_SPEED = 5
ACE = 0


class Player(arcade.Sprite):

    def update(self):
        self.center_x += self.change_x
        self.center_y += self.change_y

        if self.left < 0:
            self.left = 0
        elif self.right > SCREEN_WIDTH - 1:
            self.right = SCREEN_WIDTH - 1

        if self.bottom < 0:
            self.bottom = 0
        elif self.top > SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1:
            self.top = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1


class MyGame(arcade.Window):
    """
    Main application class.
    """

    def __init__(self, width, height, title):
        """
        Initializer
        """

        # Call the parent class initializer
        super().__init__(width, height, title)

        # Set the working directory (where we expect to find files) to the same
        # directory this .py file is in. You can leave this out of your own
        # code, but it is needed to easily run the examples using "python -m"
        # as mentioned at the top of this program.
        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        os.chdir(file_path)

        # Variables that will hold sprite lists
        self.player_list = None

        # Set up the player info
        self.player_sprite = None

        # Set the background color
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.AMAZON)

    def setup(self):
        """ Set up the game and initialize the variables. """

        # Sprite lists
        self.player_list = arcade.SpriteList()

        # Set up the player
        self.player_sprite = Player(":resources:images/animated_characters/female_person/femalePerson_idle.png", SPRITE_SCALING)
        self.player_sprite.center_x = 50
        self.player_sprite.center_y = 50
        self.player_list.append(self.player_sprite)

    def on_draw(self):
        """
        Render the screen.
        """

        # This command has to happen before we start drawing
        arcade.start_render()

        # Draw all the sprites.
        self.player_list.draw()

    def on_update(self, delta_time):
        """ Movement and game logic """

        # Call update on all sprites (The sprites don't do much in this
        # example though.)
        self.player_list.update()

    def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):
        """Called whenever a key is pressed. """
        ACE += 1

        if key == arcade.key.UP:
            self.player_sprite.change_y = MOVEMENT_SPEED
        elif key == arcade.key.DOWN:
            self.player_sprite.change_y = -MOVEMENT_SPEED
        elif key == arcade.key.LEFT:
            self.player_sprite.change_x = -MOVEMENT_SPEED
        elif key == arcade.key.RIGHT:
            self.player_sprite.change_x = MOVEMENT_SPEED

    def on_key_release(self, key, modifiers):
        """Called when the user releases a key. """

        if key == arcade.key.UP or key == arcade.key.DOWN:
            self.player_sprite.change_y = 0
        elif key == arcade.key.LEFT or key == arcade.key.RIGHT:
            self.player_sprite.change_x = 0


def main():
    """ Main method """
    window = MyGame(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)
    window.setup()
    arcade.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você quer usar a variável "ACE" como global - mas sem marcar ela explícitamente como global onde está usando, o Python entende que ela é local.

Então, pra rodar é só trocar:

```
def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):
    """Called whenever a key is pressed. """
    ACE += 1
    ...
```

por

```
def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):
    """Called whenever a key is pressed. """
    global ACE
    ACE += 1
    ...
```

No entanto, variáveis globais, embora tenham seu lugar, não são sempre uma boa ideia. Nesse caso, como você criou uma classe, faz mais sentido essa ACE ser um atributo do seu objeto, em vez de uma variável global. Para isso, é só inicializar ela dentro do método `__init__` (ou, nesse caso, do `setup`), e sempre acessa-la com o prefixo `self.`:

```py
...

class MyGame(arcade.Window):
   ...

   def setup(self):
        """ Set up the game and initialize the variables. """

        # Sprite lists
        self.player_list = arcade.SpriteList()

        # Set up the player
        self.player_sprite = Player(":resources:images/animated_characters/female_person/femalePerson_idle.png", SPRITE_SCALING)
        self.player_sprite.center_x = 50
        self.player_sprite.center_y = 50
        self.player_list.append(self.player_sprite)
        self.ACE = 0
        ...



    def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):
        """Called whenever a key is pressed. """
        self.ACE += 1
        ...
```